# call a func(argc, argv); in C

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv

I renamed one `main(int argc, char *argv[])` function to a normal sub function like `a(int argc, char *argv[]);` and call `a()` function in my `main()`.
And then, I pass the arguments. for example.

```
char *arg[10];

arg[0]="program_name";
arg[1]="-a";
arg[2]="1";
arg[3]="-b";
arg[4]="2";

a (5, arg);
```

but `a()` returns fail. `a()` stops parsing at `arg[1]` position. 
I spend three days with this problem. Any Idea ?

Comment: First of all, you should terminate the array with a `NULL` pointer. Secondly, you should probably show how the function `a` parses parameters.

Comment: Can you post full code? Plus compiler output.

Comment: It also may help to do `arg[1] = strdup("-a");` and so on for the others. The function may not be expecting pointers to constants.

Comment: If `a()` attempts to modify any of those arguments it will most likely cause a seg fault as string literals are read-only.

Comment: Obviously something goes wrong in `a`, so how'd you expect anybody to help you without having information about `a`?

Comment: thank you everyone. David's suggestion makes it work !. thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

This program works :

```
void a(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
            printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}

main( ) {
    char *arg[10];

    arg[0]="program_name";
    arg[1]="-a";
    arg[2]="1";
    arg[3]="-b";
    arg[4]="2";

    a(5, arg);
}
```

The output is :

```
5
program_name
-a
1
-b
2
```

Comment: "My car won't start when I put the key in it and turn, what should I do?" "Well, I tried that same procedure on my car, and it starts fine." Doesn't help him much, does it?

Comment: @David: depends whether he notices some difference between his code and that in this answer. If so, then it might well be helpful for him to compare his non-working code against this working code. At the very least, this answer stands as an example of how to describe what you've done, which might help the questioner ask a better question.

Comment: Calling `printf` without a prototype in scope is **Undefined Behaviour**. I suggest you `#include <stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives the called function pointers to constants, which is not what it's expecting. You can use `strdup` to generate modifiable versions of the strings you want to pass it. It's not unusual for parsers to destructively-modify data that is only expected to be used once. This won't work if the data is constant.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the debugger and step into the `a(...)` function to see exactly what's happening.